# Kendo Tree list removes the css classes after expand and collapsing nodes

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I have added CSS classes to particular child element in kendo tree list in DataBound Event as:

```
dataBound: function (e) {                      
    var treeview = $("#grid").data("kendoTreeList");
    var treeData =  treeview.dataSource.data();

    for(var i =0; i< treeData.length; i++) {
        if(treeData[i].parentId ==1 || treeData[i].parentId == 2 || treeData[i].parentId==3) {
            var row = treeview.content.find("tr[data-uid=" + treeData[i].uid + "]");
            row.addClass("grossMarginSegment");
        }
    }
}
```

Also same class is applied to three parent elements as follows:

```
var dataItem =  treeview.dataSource.get(1);
var row = treeview.content.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]");
row.addClass("grossMarginSegment");    

var dataItem =  treeview.dataSource.get(2);
var row = treeview.content.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]");
row.addClass("grossMarginSegment");

var dataItem = treeview.dataSource.get(3);
var row = treeview.content.find("tr[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]");
row.addClass("grossMarginSegment");
```

When I expand and collapse some of the node is in tree view the
classes applied to some of the nodes gets removed.

Code in exapnd event :

```
expand: function (e) {                  
    Title = e.model.Title;
    ParentId = e.model.parentId;                   
}
```

Couldn't find the reason

Comment: You need to use [templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) instead of adding classes in the elements directly. Kendo's widgets creates and re-creates elements all the time, that is why the classs are lost. Can you provide a demo of your issue in dojo.telerik.com ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for the reply !!!!!. Actually i am not able to put demo as data-source is API call. Do you have any example where templates are used for such customized operations ?

Comment: Just set your [data as a static json](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-data) generated by your api, then you'll be able to create a demo

Comment: It is exactly same as http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding